# how to limit results that are returned in a PHP array

Tags: php

I have this `foreach` loop in PHP where i loop through some array results:

```
foreach(array_reverse($output) as $row)
```

but i want to be able to limit the number of results so i can display the results on separate pages

i have tried using the function `array_slice` in PHP but had no luck, using the below code i just get no results returned

```
foreach(array_reverse(array_slice($output),0,5) as $row)
```

how can i limit the results returned in the array?

Comment: You can split an array into chunks with [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

Comment: The closing bracket for `array_slice` is misplaced, `array_slice` takes 3 arguments.

Comment: Where is the information coming from?  If it is a database you can limit the amount of rows in your query.

Comment: If this is from a SQL query, use `LIMIT` instead

Comment: Just for example, when running your code I get an error: `array_slice() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in...`. You can see it here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/g00O6N

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put the offset and limit in the array_reverse method arguments instead of the array_slice arguments.

`array array_reverse ( array $array [, bool $preserve_keys = false ] )`

`array array_slice ( array $array , int $offset [, int $length = NULL [, bool $preserve_keys = false ]] )`